# Add one year to existing Google sheet strings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I use to keep track of my income/spends within my (one-man) company. One could argue that google sheets isn't the best tool for that, but it works best for me considering a number of reasons.

The only real problem is when I prepare the document for a new year. I have a lot of formulas calculating all sorts of things, and usually I just change the year for each and every one manually. But I'm wondering if there is a easier way to to this, some kind of "add one year to all dates in this sheet"-script.

The formulas aren't pure dates, but with a lot of other information in them as well. I post an example of how they could look below.

I don't know much about coding, so perhaps this is impossible due to whatever obvious reasons for you programmers, but I thought I might as well ask since I rather not spend my Christmas updating all million dates by hand (exaggerating but you get it!).

How do I change the following formula to be year-independent?

```
=(SUMIFS('Händelser'!$I$4:$I$101;'Händelser'!$K$4:$K$101;">=200101";'Händelser'!$K$4:$K$101;"<=200131")+$D$6)-(SUMIFS('Händelser'!$Q$4:$Q$101;'Händelser'!$S$4:$S$101;">=200101";'Händelser'!$S$4:$S$101;"<=200131")+$D$7)
```

Another example of formula:

```
=(SUMIFS('Händelser'!$G:$G;'Händelser'!$E:$E;">=200201";'Händelser'!$E:$E;"<=200231"))/20
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just realised one could "search and replace" in google sheet, and have it search not only through the text written out but also through the formulas behind it. I just searched and replaced "=20" with "=21" and it all worked out nicely.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Great that you were able to check it with yourself. But wouldn't this replace `2020` to `2121`? Also, what about the dates that are not `2020`? Will it be expected that it will be as is? `"add one year to all dates in this sheet"-script.` description in the post above says that all dates will be incremented to 1 year

Comment: All the dates in the original document were year 2020 and by replacing "=20" and not just "20" I worked around the issue of making 2020 to 2121. Not the cleanest way perhaps but it worked haha!